# Text entry value to be saved on browser's local storage

Tags: javascript

The code below is to press a button to show a text entry for user to type in and text to be saved to local storage when clicking elsewhere.

The text field appears but after I type something in it and click away, the text doesn't get saved on local storage.

Comment: Where is `itemValue` defined?

Comment: You didnt define itemValue anywhere

Comment: How would I do that to get the text typed in the text field?

Comment: I have changed the one before last line of code to  localStorage.setItem(itemKey, initialText); Then the item saved in local storage is empty, I'm failing to make it capture whatever is typed on the text field.

Comment: I can see a `textarea` being created. `var textElement = document.createElement("textarea");`. Do you want to save the value of this `textarea` to `localStorage`?

Comment: Yes please. I tried that with this localStorage.setItem(itemKey, itemValue);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this...

```js
function saveEntry(event) {
    //...
    //...
    localStorage.setItem(itemKey, event.target.value);
  }
```